# Which IDE works best for coding firebase cloud functions?

Tags: ide, typescript, firebase

**Problem:**
I currently use Sublime and hate working in Visual Studios.

**Background:**
I use Android Studios to work on my Flutter app and love it so much, but it doesn't really work for Cloud Functions since that uses TypeScript.

**Main Issue**
Sublime isn't good enough to catch basic issues that I find every time I build the project and it also falls short when trying to investigate references to functions or jumping to declarations.

**Possible Solutions**
I have a MacBook and have Xcode but don't know if it would be any better than Sublime for a TypeScript project. I have Visual Studio Code but it just seems like a mess to setup. My intuition tells me Xcode could be a hidden gem to work on but I haven't had luck in my casual attempts to try it.

I think IntelliJ might be good but I don't know if it's worth paying that absurd subscription fee especially if it ends up not working too well.

**Question**
Are there IDEs that play well with a Cloud Function project while being more powerful than Sublime and less cumbersome than Visual Studios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used IntelliJ. It has TS support.